# How to pass {useMasterKey: true} to a parse-server js aggregate query?

Tags: mongodb, parse-server

I want to do an aggregate query using parse-server js. 
Something of the style of the following code, but instead of using .find(), using .aggregate(pipeline, options).

```js
const query = new Parse.Query("myClass");
query.find().then( // ... do something with the resulting objects)
)
```

According to the docs (https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.0/Parse.Query.html#aggregate), aggregate requires the masterkey to be used. However, the options parameter of the call to .aggregate(pipeline, options) does not allow for the passing of an object that has the field to use the masterkey defined.

The workarounds found online suggest the use of Parse.Cloud.useMasterkey, which has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the master key during the initialization of your Parse SDK. At some point in your code you probably initialize the connection with the Parse Server using a code similar to this:

```js
Parse.serverURL = 'http://url_to_parse_server.com'
Parse.initialize('appId')
```

What you have to do is to pass two new parameters in the `.initialize` function above. The second parameter is a key to use the JS SDK, but if didn't set this key in your Parse Server then you can pass `null` in this parameter.

The third parameter is what you are looking for and here is where you will put the master key. Like this:

```js
Parse.initialize('appId', null, 'master key')
```

After you do that all the API calls that require the master key, like `aggregate` will use it automatically.

Comment: hey! I am not from the web development world, but what is the master key. I kind of authorisation token?

Answer (score -1):

There are actually two libraries at play here. Firstly, there is Parse Server - where they requirement for the use of the MasterKey is coming from.

Then there is the Parse JS SDK (to which your documentation link points) - which is the environment which Cloud Code uses to talk to Parse Server.

If you look at the source code for the aggregate function in the JS SDK, it appears that they set the MasterKey automatically: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/8a69f9504f398187a856797c4b037b8eb6804dd8/src/ParseQuery.js#L763

So your query *should* just work, without you having to set the MasterKey explicitly from the JS SD call.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. The aggregate function uses the master key, but it actually needs to be set before during the initialization, otherwise it won't work. There is no such thing as "should just work".